# Python send email with an attachment

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, mime

I'm testing out Python, learning how to use it.

Recently I've been testing out different ways to send e-mails using SMTP, without and with attachments.

So far, after reading the Python documentation and other topics here on Stackoverflow I got what I needed and now can send emails with attachments, yay me!

I stumbled across this page, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm, which offered what it looks like to me, another way to attach files.

I used this before in a script where I had 4 files to attach (lets hope I insert the code correctly):

```
   for f in attach:
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload(open(f, 'rb').read())
    Encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
    msg.attach(part)
```

But the tutorial posted above uses a different way and I tried it out because why not, just copy and paste and enter my email, SMTP just to see it in action, and try changes after. However, the last bit of code:

```
message = part1 + part2 + part3
```

.. does not work. My SMTP refuses saying [ERNO10053]. Just sending one part works fine.

Could someone who is more familiar in Python explain to me what it means to use boundaries? I can see that it is "--" followed by a unique marker. But I don't understand really why you need them, and whats going on in this script really.

I'm a newb.

Cheers!

Comment: so look up what your smtp's server error #10053 is.

Comment: That is a good idea, will do.

Comment: I *think* you're looking for documentation on [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) (and should tag the question so).

Comment: Looks like server side blocking. It may occurred by mail server antivirus. Or server rejected some type of files. Try with different type of files (.doc, .jpg, etc.).

Comment: I tried to change to a different file. If I only send part3, which contains the "encodedcontent", it works with any file. But when I match the three parts as mentioned in the tutorial I get that error. And I really dont understand the "border, marker" thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This boundaries is part of [MIME specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages). They are used as separator between attachments.

Error [10053](http://support.ipswitch.com/kb/WSK-19980702-EM02.htm) means connection abort.